# How can I show all divs at once while using ngswitchngSwitchCase?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ng-switch

I have the following code:

```
  <div class="box" *ngSwitchCase="'financing'">
  <div class="box" *ngSwitchCase="'procurement'">
  <div class="box" *ngSwitchCase="'operations'">
```

I am using the `ngSwitchCase` to switch between the divs depending on what the user selects. However, I want to add one last switch case that allows the user to view all three divs at one, as follows:

```
 <div class="box" *ngSwitchCase="'financing'">
 <div class="box" *ngSwitchCase="'procurement'">
 <div class="box" *ngSwitchCase="'operations'">
  <div class="box" *ngSwitchCase="'summary'">
```

The way I have it now is that the summary part contains all the of the contents of the upper 3 divs.

How can I achieve the same case but without repeating my code?

Comment: You could use `ngIf` instead if you don't actually want the mutually exclusive behaviour of `ngSwitch`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe wouldn't I still in that case still need to copy all of the contents into the summary div?

Comment: No, you show each div if either only it should be shown or all should be shown. `*ngIf="whatever == 'summary' || whatever == 'operations'"`.